# Why do I get this undefined property error message in my promise?

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios

When my `axios` call fails, the code in `catch()` correctly displays the error message contained in err.response.data.message, which is defined.

But when the `axios` call succeeds, I get this error in console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

How to fix that?

Here's my `axios` call code:

```
mounted () {
  this.$axios.$get(`http://example.com/wp-json/project/v1/post/${this.$route.params.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      this.title = res.post_title
      this.content = res.post_content
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.$toast.error(err.response.data.message)
    })
```

Comment: Did you `console.log()` the contents of `err`? As the error message states quite clearly, `err.response` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, it's never working whether the axios call succeeds or not. But the $toast.error works normally when axios call fails. It's very strange

Answer (score 0):

Try `res.data.post_title` instead of `res.post_title`

```
...
.then((res) => {
  this.title = res.data.post_title
  this.content = res.data.post_content
})
...
```

Axios return an object containing the following information

```
{
  data: {},        // the response that was provided by the server
  status: 200,     // the HTTP status code from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',// the HTTP status message from the server response
  headers: {},     // the headers that the server responded with
  config: {},      // the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  request: {}      // the request that generated this response
}
```

If you steal get the same error, then it's probably a server side mal-formatted data, try to console.log the response and see if there any problem serve side.

```
...
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.config);
  });
...
```